# Current status "with editor" after a a mix up

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics, editors

My paper was accepted from the Mathematics Magazine. They told me that there are some corrections and changes that I should do and I could find them in the PDF attachment which already appeared in the editorial management system.

The problem is that the PDF was not about my paper.

I sent several mails to let them know about the mix up and finally they answered that "I will inform the editor about the mix up" etc.
Before two months I uploaded a "revised" submission (I made *some* corrections but not all since I did not have the PDF) but I did not click on "approve revision".
Suddenly, today I got an email which says that they confirm my revision and the status of my paper is "With Editor".
What is happening?

Comment: If you're not sure, ask _them_.  I don't see how anyone here can answer this question, as it's fairly specific to your situation.

Comment: @ff524 Basically I would like to know what "With editor" means...

Comment: _Basically I would like to know what "With editor" means._ In that case, I believe this is already answered [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like).

Comment: First of all, congratulations for your paper. With editor means that the editor has to send the paper forward, look [here at APS, the Mathematics Magazine might have a different style](http://journals.aps.org/authors/tips-authors-physical-review-physical-review-letters).